# KDevelop "failed to lock session" after crash

Tags: kdevelop

My machine crashed with KDevelop running, and after rebooting it won't start, saying:

> Failed to lock the session, probably it is already active in another running instance

However I definitely do not have it running anywhere.

How can I clear up whatever kind of lock it created and failed to clean up after itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually remove any KDevelop lock files via:

```
sudo rm ~/.kde/share/apps/kdevelop/sessions/*/lock
```

Comment: In recent versions (KDE 5) the location might have changed to `~/.local/share/kdevelop/sessions/*/lock`, at least based on what I'm seeing on my non-Ubuntu system. Maybe someone else can check this on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

[The accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/317544/6228) did nothing for me, however I didn't reboot my PC to try to fix the problem.

What worked for me was this:

```
killall -9 kdevelop
```

After killing all instances of kdevelop, I could start it again, and pick a session.